# Group partners from one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in one table named claim.files, the first column is named ‘claim’ and contains the claim file numbers ex. 4355, 6444, 7674 etc, and the second is named ‘partner’ and contains the partner code for ex. 8393, 4783, 38283.
The claim file number is unique but every claim file can have more partners so I want to run a select which can group all the partners for each claim file. if I run this “select claim, partner from claim.files where claim in (4355, 6444, 7674) group by claim, partner” it will duplicate the claim if it has more partners.

I want the result to be like below:

```
claim  partners
4355   57878, 45874, 58977
```

If i run the below code it will duplicate the claim number

```
select claim, partner from claim.files where claim in (4355, 6444, 7674) group by claim, partner
```

This how the result will be if i run the above select

```
 claim  partners
   4355  57878
   4355  45874
   4355  58977
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: pls post a correct sql statement. what is this snr ? Group by works only with functions like sum() or average()

Comment: please explain how a claim can have more partners if they are unique and where does snr come in to the picture.

Comment: sorry, i edited now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the partners comma separated for each `claim`, you can use [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select claim, group_concat(partner separator ',') as partners
from files 
where snr in (4355, 6444, 7674) 
group by claim;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e80514/1):

```
| claim |          partners |
|-------|-------------------|
|  4355 | 57878,45874,58977 |
```

---

**Updated:** If you are using SQL server, you can do this instead:

```
SELECT
    f1.claim,
    STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + CAST(f2.partner AS NVARCHAR(50))
          FROM files as f2
          where snr in (4355, 6444, 7674) 
            and f1.claim = f2.claim
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS partners
FROM files as f1
where snr in (4355, 6444, 7674) 
group by f1.claim;
```

-[SQL Server demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58a4c/3)

```
| claim |          partners |
|-------|-------------------|
|  4355 | 57878,45874,58977 |
```

Comment: @haxx What do you mean by sql client? how it doesn't work? doesn't provide the expected results? or do you got errors?

Comment: i got errors : Error: [SQL0204] GROUP_CONCAT in *LIBL type *N not found.
SQLState:  42704
ErrorCode: -204

Comment: @haxx Are you using sql server or mysql?? You are tagging you question with MySQL tag!!!! The function I am using, is mysql sepecific .

Comment: @haxx - See my updated answer for sql server solution.

Comment: it isn't sql server, i use an sql client named "squirrel sql"  to connect at the database, it is a DB2 type database